# I believe the -O2 flag is causing me to have to recompile on each machine. Why?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, openframeworks

I am building a project using a library (openFrameworks) and the default options set in the compiler for the release target included the `-O2` flag, which I have never used. Until recently, I thought nothing of it because everything seemed to be working. I then began testing on machines that were not being used in development and the programs crashed (it didn't even get to any of my debug statements).

Recompiling on the target machine itself makes the executable work correctly. Is the `-O2` flag possibly causing this? I get no errors or warnings when recompiling on the target machine, so I'm not quite sure why this is happening. The reason I suspect the `-O2` flag is because it's the only one I've never used that's enabled in the project.

I have not tested yet whether it happens in the `-O1` or `-O3` flags.

I am on windows 7 and all my tests have been on Windows 7 and Windows 8 systems, compiled using MinGW(TDM-GCC) 4.8.1 in Code::Blocks.

Comment: I doubt it's a problem with the compiler flag, many projects use `-O2` as default. I'd bet on undefined behaviour. That said with the information you gave there's no way for any real answer.

Comment: The problem is I have no idea where the problem would be, and posting pages of code isn't exactly constructive. Is there something I can do that would be helpful?

Comment: Step through it with the debugger. Set a breakpoint right at `main()` and then step forward until you find the thing that breaks. If it crashes before even reaching `main()` it can only be a problem with static (global) variable initialization since they are the only things that run before main. Or actually a problem with the -O2 which I still find unlikely.

Comment: Try clangs (and gcc has it to by now I think) sanitizers (`-fsanitize=undefined` for undefined behavior, `=memory` for memory related,...) Read their manuals though.

Comment: Running the crashing executable under GDB and getting a stacktrace might be helpful. openFrameworks claims to be compatible with Visual C++, so you might also try building using Visual Studio and see what its debugger tells you (the new VS Community 2013 might be a good option if you don't have a license for Visual Studio: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx)

Comment: check the architecture you are compiling for with `gcc -dumpmachine`. the extra optimization flags could assume that a certain cpu instruction exists because of the architecture settings when on the target machine it doesnt. to fix try compiling with `-march` and the correct architecture (to find the correct architecture run the prev command on the target machine).

Answer (score -2):

The -O2 flag:  Optimize even more than -O flag.  GCC performs nearly all supported optimizations that do not involve a space-speed tradeoff. The compiler does not perform loop unrolling or function inlining when you specify '-O2'. As compared to '-O', this option increases both compilation time and the performance of the generated code.

'-O2' turns on all optimization flags specified by '-O'. It also turns on the following optimization flags: 
-fforce-mem -foptimize-sibling-calls -fstrength-reduce -fcse-follow-jumps -fcse-skip-blocks -frerun-cse-after-loop -frerun-loop-opt -fgcse -fgcse-lm -fgcse-sm -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fexpensive-optimizations -fregmove -fschedule-insns -fschedule-insns2 -fsched-interblock -fsched-spec -fcaller-saves -fpeephole2 -freorder-blocks -freorder-functions -fstrict-aliasing -falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-loops -falign-labels

The result is that any architecture or OS differences are going to cause a memory fault or bad branch.  When you take a compiled executable or library that is optimized it is going to utilize all the specific hardware available on that platform.  If you have an apples to apples hardware comparison and OS that are all identical, you have a shot at it working, but even then it is hard to make a determination until you try it at run time.  The problem is that it is dependent on the specifics of the compiler and is not generalized.

Comment: C++ is usually compiled to native machine code and naturally doesn't work across different OSes like windows <-> mac without recompiling. That said there's nothing in `-O2` that makes it less portable and I frequently use software compiled with `-o2` and `-O3` across Windows 7, 8 and XP without any problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I should have made a comment rather than an "answer".  I have had an optimization cause this kind of inconsistent behavior, but I suppose it was a different OS combination.  Probably more likely to be an uninitialized global thus depending on the memory state of the different runs.

Comment: I just want to note that even the more specialized `-mtune=architecture` tunes code for one specific architecture but still allows other architectures to run the code by having multiple different code paths. The only way to completely make it dependent on an architecture would be `-march=architecture` which tells it to optimize and compile only for that one specified architecture.

Comment: Quick question: are you saying `-march=architecture` would cause it to not work on other machines? It seems `-march=native` was enabled in the project.

Comment: Correct.  `-march=native` will allow GCC to use any of the instructions that are available on the compiling machine.  A slightly older machine would then not be able to run the software.  Choose a value for `-march=architecture` which represents the oldest processor you want be able to run on.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test without that flag in the next few days and see how it goes and then post an answer if it works.